# Issues with Xen and Routed networking

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, debian-jessie

I have spent the last Severn days trying to get this working but guides out there are either vague or outdated at the bottom of this post I have added links to some of the guides I tried to follow. I have a dedicated machine at hetzner and I want to setup virtualisation I can create the vm's no problem the issue I have is with networking, on the hetzner network you can't use a simple bridge because they route any additional subnets to your hosts main ip and won't accept packets if the mac address does not match the host machine.

I have worked out that I need to use routed networks to route my subnet through my eth0 connection I have tried again and again and I can never get the networking to work I can never access out of my vm at all not even to dom0, I can usually ssh into the servers from the address I assigned it from dom0 I have run tcpdump and ping packets are reaching dom0 when they are mean't for a domU but it is just stopping there and not getting to the domU.

The one solution I tried was to use virtualizor and that worked first time my idea then was to just take the config of that and replicate it without the control panel as I don't need one and paying for something I don't need seems pointless to me as I am the only user of this machine and its vm's.

I am using debian based operating systems and the xl tool as I am mainly using Debian Jessie, I want to OS to be within a reasonable support range for security updates I have also tried Ubuntu from 14.04 upwards. I think the issue is the interfaces file setup but I don't know whats wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated

[Routed XEN VM based on LVM](https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Routed_XEN_VM_based_on_LVM_(step-by-step_for_Hetzner_DS3000))
[Hetzner Xen IPv4 Subnet + IPv6 Subnet](https://gist.github.com/pulsar256/5f901a7fa903fae6332e)
[Setting Up XEN on Hetzner Dedicated Server](https://gist.github.com/omarqureshi/3811310)
[Setting Up Ubuntu 12.04 and Xen on Hetzner](http://clarkdave.net/2012/11/setting-up-ubuntu-12-04-and-xen-on-hetzner/)

Comment: Do you want your VM to have a public IP address?

Comment: Yes I have a subnet of public ipv4 addresses

Comment: It's been a while since I had a subnet. With individual IPs, you can now use a self-service button in the Robot user interface to assign a different MAC address. Maybe you can do that with individual IPs from the subnet, too?

Comment: No for some reason they don't allow you to do that on subnets. I did check with support though as I have had individual IPs on my old box a few years ago and you could to the virtual MAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual machine networking configuration for routed mode on Hetzner, OVH, and Online.net servers is counterintuitive because you have networks that resemble this:

```
Host IP:       192.168.0.2
Host Netmask:  255.255.255.0 (/24)
Host Gateway:  192.168.0.1

Guest IP:      10.0.0.1
Guest Netmask: 255.255.255.255 (/32)
Guest Gateway: 192.168.0.1
Guest MAC:     02:00:00:01:02:03
```

<sup><sub>The example above is just an illustration, not sample IP addresses you can expect from any of the aforementioned hosting providers.</sub></sup>

Huh?  What?  How can you have a subnet of just one IP address (`10.0.0.1/32`)?  There's no room for a gateway!  Why is the gateway on a very different subnet (`192.168.0.0/24`)?

These are the questions that make Linux and Windows fail their networking sanity checks, since the networks make no sense to them.  They think that the gateway would be unreachable.

Hetzner, OVH, and Online.net use some network trickery that make the gateway reachable anyway.

Fortunately, on both Linux and Windows, you can override the sanity checks and set the above interface configuration.

---

## Possible Solutions

### Static Addressing

This is the easiest to do.  The most configuration you need to do on the host is to create a bridge.

#### Host

On **Debian/Ubuntu**, if your management/Internet interface is `eth0`, you can edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to have a bridge `br0` like so:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.2   # Host IP
        netmask 255.255.255.0 # Host Netmask
        gateway 192.168.0.1   # Host Gateway
        metric 0
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp on
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

Run `sudo service networking restart` to make the bridged networking configuration take effect.

On **RHEL/CentOS**, if your management/Internet interface is `eth0`, you can edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to use bridge `br0` like so:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
BRIDGE="br0"
```

Then create a new file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0` to configure the bridge:

```
DEVICE="br0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR="192.168.0.2"    # Host IP
NETMASK="255.255.255.0" # Host Netmask
GATEWAY="192.168.0.1"   # Host Gateway
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Bridge"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
```

Run `sudo service network restart` to make the bridged networking configuration take effect.

If you remain connected to your server, congrats, you've got a working bridge!

#### Hypervisor

On pure [**Xen xl**](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/XL) (libxenlight), this is all you need to write for the virtual interface configuration:

```
vif=[ 'mac=02:00:00:01:02:03,bridge=br0' ]
```

Note that `02:00:00:01:02:03` is the MAC address that Hetzner, OVH, or Online.net gave you for the guest's network, and `br0` is the bridge that we just configured above.

If you're using [**libvirt**](https://libvirt.org/), inside the `<devices>` tag, add this interface:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='02:00:00:01:02:03'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
</interface>
```

Once you have this virtual interface configured with the right MAC address and bridge, boot up your guest and connect to its console (`xl console domU`, `virsh console domU`, or attach to the guest's VNC session, if applicable).

#### Guest

Here comes the ugly part.  It varies by operating system on how to override the networking sanity checks.  I'll cover **Debian/Ubuntu**, **RHEL/CentOS**, and **Microsoft Windows NT**.

On **Debian/Ubuntu**, if the interface is called `eth0`, write this into `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.1    # Guest IP
        broadcast 10.0.0.1  # Guest IP
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        gateway 192.168.0.1 # Guest Gateway, a.k.a. Host Gateway
        post-up route add 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
        post-up route add default gw 192.168.0.1
        pre-down route del 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
        pre-down route del default gw 192.168.0.1
```

The `post-up` and `post-down` iproute2 commands tell the operating system to apply the gateway anyway, even though it's on a different subnet.

After running `sudo service networking restart`, you should now be able to reach your guest through Guest IP `10.0.0.1`.

On **RHEL/CentOS**, if the interface is called `eth0`, write this into `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="none"
ONBOOT="yes"
USERCTL="no"
PEERDNS="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
NETMASK="255.255.255.255"
IPADDR="10.0.0.1"          # Guest IP
GATEWAY="192.168.0.1"      # Guest Gateway, a.k.a. Host Gateway
ARP="yes"
HWADDR="02:00:00:01:02:03" # Guest MAC
```

Then, write the following into `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0`:

```
192.168.0.1 dev eth0
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

This file tells iproute2 to apply the gateway anyway, even though it's on a different subnet.

After running `sudo service network restart`, you should now be able to reach your guest through Guest IP `10.0.0.1`.

On **Microsoft Windows NT**, go to Network Connections in Control Panel, right-click the interface, and click "Properties".  Under the "Networking" tab, choose "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)", then click "Properties".  Fill in the fields as shown:

[image: Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) Properties]

When you click "OK", you'll get this warning:

[image: Microsoft TCP/IP: Warning - The default gateway is not on the same network segment (subnet) that is defined by the IP address and subnet mask. Do you want to save this configuration?]

Click "OK" to confirm that you want to use the gateway anyway.

After a few seconds, you should be able to reach your guest through Guest IP `10.0.0.1`.

### DHCP Dynamic Addressing

Unfortunately, this is not possible.  No DHCP server is going to assign you `10.0.0.1/32` and tell you the gateway is `192.168.0.1`, even if you somehow intercepted the guest's DHCPDISCOVER.  And no DHCP client is going to accept this bizarre configuration.

You need a properly structured network with a gateway inside your subnet in order to set up DHCP.  The only way to do this is to create a private network (`172.16.0.0/12`) and do network address translation between your guest's private IP address (`172.16.0.2`) and its public IP address (`10.0.0.1`) via the gateway (`172.16.0.1`).

### Private Network and NAT

Although I've verified all the steps above, I never successfully created a *one-to-one/basic* NAT from private IPs to public IPs.  Part of the reason is that there's a lot to do to build the networks.

Your network could look like this:

```
Guest Public IP:  10.0.0.1
Guest Private IP: 172.16.0.2
Guest Netmask:    255.240.0.0 (/12)
Guest Gateway:    172.16.0.1
```

The host would then forward traffic between Guest Public IP `10.0.0.1` and Guest Private IP `172.16.0.2` via Guest Gateway `172.16.0.1`.

[OpenStack](https://www.openstack.org/) (which [supports Xen via libvirt](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/HypervisorSupportMatrix)) could potentially provide this NAT setup as well as a private subnet DHCP server through its network abstraction, [OpenStack Neutron](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Neutron), but setting up OpenStack itself is quite a hassle.

I was able to get a single-node OpenStack installation and Neutron private networks running for Nova instances/guests/servers, but I could not figure out how to NAT the private IP addresses (`172.16.0.0/12`) to external network IP addresses (`10.0.0.1/32`, `10.0.0.2/32`, and so on) because OpenStack doesn't support Hetzner's, OVH's, and Online.net's unusual networking structure for virtual machines out-of-the-box.  This remains an unsolved problem.

---

## Additional Resources

- OVH: [How to configure hosts for the distributions of virtualization to bridge?](http://help.ovh.com/BridgeClient)
- Super User: [Another answer I gave on bridging networks](https://superuser.com/a/1101190/83694), also covers one-to-many NAT

Comment: I appreciate the answer and it does clear a lot up I was using a subnet though and they don't assign mac addresses for subnets

Comment: @bobthemac: I guess my information on Hetzner was a bit off, but you may be able to use any arbitrary MAC address with Hetzner.  Hetzner has a different suggestion according to [their own documentation](https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/KVM_mit_Nutzung_aller_IPs_aus_Subnetz/en).  They also have a NAT script in that article, so that could be useful if you choose to go the private network route.

Comment: I have tried using their scripts before with no luck. I need to check how many single ip's I can as I found out you can get mac's assigned to them, might be the simplest way to get it working.