# Unlock ADVANCED menu on sony vaio laptop bios

Tags: virtualbox, bios

I am using a Sony Vaio VGN-CS220J and am trying to get to the "ADVANCED" tab of the bios so I can turn on virtualization so I can get 64 bit OS choices in Virtual Box.  I've looked online but have only found ways to do it for other Sony Vaio laptop models.  Is there a way I can do it? 
EDIT: I am using Windows Vista Home Premium 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CPU doesn't support hardware virtualization (VT-x).

[Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor T6400 (2M Cache, 2.00 GHz, 800 MHz FSB)](https://ark.intel.com/products/40479/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T6400-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but do you know if that means I can't run 64 bit OS's inside of Virtual Box?

Comment: That is a different question, but has been answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/749355/64-bit-windows-guest-in-virtualbox-impossible-without-vt-x-support