# Could not detect the operating system in disc image of kali linux

Tags: vmware-workstation, kali-linux

I am trying to create a virtual machine using VMware Workstation 12. When i am choosing iso image during installation it do not detect the operating system.

[image]

Comment: Can you choose Kali Linux if you continue?

Comment: I choose linux from menu but kali linux is missing from submenu.

Comment: Can you choose 64bits machines in general? Since you need VT-x for this, also look here: http://superuser.com/questions/156859/vmware-this-host-doesnt-support-vt-can-not-play-64bit-vm-due-to-lack-of-vt-fl

Comment: I have already enabled virtual hardware in BIOS

Comment: For your intended use, [Kali Linux is practically Debian](http://askubuntu.com/a/470745/18979).  Select **Debian** from the submenu.

Comment: Thanks @Deltik which version of debian is it 6 or 7?

Comment: [Kali Linux is based on Debian Wheezy](http://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-relationship-with-debian), which is Debian 7.

Comment: You're welcome, @Beginner.  You can accept [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/998557/83694) if it was what you were looking for.  As a side note, I suggest that you [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/998491/edit) to ask a question because as it currently stands, it is unclear what you were asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you wrote in [your comment](https://superuser.com/questions/998491/could-not-detect-the-operating-system-in-disc-image-of-kali-linux?noredirect=1#comment1379535_998491), you wanted to know what operating system to tell VMware Workstation to consider Kali Linux 2.0.

Since [Kali Linux is based on Debian Wheezy](http://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-relationship-with-debian) (Debian 7), you should tell VMware Workstation that you are installing Debian 7.